# Como guardar fecha de datapicker en postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

Me encuentro con este pequeño problema al guardar la fecha me guarda la del presente y no la seleccionada en java.

Codigo en el controller

```
fac.setFecha_fin(dateFecha.getConverter().toString());
```

Codigo sentencia

```
insert into factura (fecha_fin) values (?);
```

Comment: En ese caso no es una problema de servidor es mas bien de programacion, PostgreSQL acepta varios tipos de datos fecha, como timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone o simplemente un date. tendriamos que ver como se declaro el campo en la base de datos, y ver como estas recibiendo el argumento fecha en tu aplicacion. por lo que dice suena a un getDate().

Comment: lo declare character varying en la bd.

Comment: Yo veo que la fecha para que la puedas guardar como String debes de darle un formato primero y no solo toString

Comment: esta fue la solucion y guardo correctamente

fac.setFecha_fin(dateFecha.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));